# WooCommerce not letting me add custom column to shop_order post type

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, add-filter

I just started writing a plugin and ran into a problem right away. I want to add a column to the order overview page in the WooCommerce admin. The straight forward filter below doesn't do anything. Replacing `shop_order` with `post` or `product`, however, does show the extra column on the respective overview page.

```
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'add_sales_column'); 
function add_sales_column($columns) {
    $columns['order_sales'] = "Sales";
    return $columns;
}
```

Trying this on:
WC Version:     2.1.5
WP Version:     3.8.1

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that we have to wait for WooCommerce to finish its setup. This goes two ways, first running all our hooks inside a `plugins_loaded` main hook, and then setting the priority of our hooks for something greater than WC's.

```php
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'setup_so_22237380' );

function setup_so_22237380() 
{
    // Just to make clear how the filters work
    $posttype = "shop_order";

    // Priority 20, with 1 parameter (the 1 here is optional)
    add_filter( "manage_edit-{$posttype}_columns", 'column_set_so_22237380', 20, 1 ); 

    // Priority 20, with 2 parameters
    add_action( "manage_{$posttype}_posts_custom_column", 'column_display_so_22237380', 20, 2 ); 

    // Default priority, default parameters (zero or one)
    add_filter( "manage_edit-{$posttype}_sortable_columns", 'column_sort_so_22237380' ); 
}


function column_set_so_22237380( $columns )
{
    $columns['order_sales'] = "Sales";
    return $columns;
}


function column_display_so_22237380( $column_name, $post_id ) 
{
    if ( 'order_sales' != $column_name )
        return;

    $sales_information = 'Your custom get_order_sales_information($post_id)';

    if ( $sales_information )
        echo "<strong style='color:#f00;'> $sales_information </strong>";
}

function column_sort_so_22237380( $columns ) 
{
    $columns['order_sales'] = 'order_sales';
    return $columns;
}
```

Setting the column as *sortable* is optional (`manage_edit-{$posttype}_sortable_columns`) and needs an extra action hook to make it work (`pre_get_posts`). This may be a complex function to build and requires its [own research](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=_sortable_columns).

Answer (score 4):

I encountered a similar issue when adding a custom column to the WooCommerce Orders overview page from my theme's `functions.php` file. I was able to get a custom column to show up by increasing the filter priority above the default value of 10. Try replacing your code with the following:

```
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'add_sales_column', 11);    
function add_sales_column($columns) {
    $columns['order_sales'] = "Sales";
    return $columns;
}
```

Tested on WP 3.9.1 and WC 2.1.12.

Check out the [WordPress Codex entry on `add_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) for more details on the behavior of filters using the `$priority` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wanting to implement this when using Woocommerce with
HPOS (High-Performance Order Storage)

There are other hooks to use:

- FILTER: `woocommerce_shop_order_list_table_columns( string $columns )`
- ACTION: `woocommerce_shop_order_list_table_custom_column( string $column, WC_Order $order )`

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_order_list_table_columns', function ( string $columns ) {
    $columns['custom_column'] = 'My Custom Column';
    return $columns;
} );

add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_order_list_table_custom_column', function ( string $column, WC_Order $order ) {
    if ( 'custom_column' !== $column ) {
        return;
    }
}, 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

It will working fine if you include all the order hook on

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'setup_all_order_column_hook' );

function setup_all_order_column_hook(){
 //Just to make clear how the filters work
    $posttype = "shop_order";

//Priority 20, with 1 parameter (the 1 here is optional)

add_filter( "manage_edit-{$posttype}_columns", 'column_set_so_22237380', 20, 1 ); 

//Priority 20, with 2 parameters

add_action( "manage_{$posttype}_posts_custom_column",column_display_so_22237380', 20, 2 ); 

// Default priority, default parameters (zero or one)

add_filter( "manage_edit-{$posttype}_sortable_columns",'column_sort_so_22237380' ); 
}
```